# Appcelerator Listview how to display dynamic text and images inline?

Tags: listview, appcelerator

I am using a listview to display messages from users. A message may have multiple images. For example,

```
Lorem ipsum [image1]
Lorem ipsum [image1] Lorem ipsum [image2]
[image1] Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum [image2] Lorem ipsum [image3]
and so on...
```

How do I display each dynamic message in the listview row?

Comment: Is there a defined template that can be followed or is that that the number of label and imageview can vary to any degree. The reason for asking is because either ListView or TableView will required a defined number of templates to work smooth and effectively.

Comment: The number of text and image in a single message is unpredictable.

Comment: Then this would mean that there is no defined template and that each row will be a unique one. This would mean high memory usage, slow performance and other issues. I would suggest you to figure out a different approach. If same templates can be reused for the tableview or listview, then you get a better usage out of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a WebView for each ItemTemplate:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView

Comment: How can WebView resolve the above requirement and won't it make the approach heavy ?

Comment: That would be one webview per listview row and the loading and scrolling will be very slow.